Trying to add records in RAG vector database Pinecone
Hello All I am trying creating a RAG chatbot, that does a POST request when user clicks add. The purpose of the add, is to add the record in the RAG vector database. I can't seem to format the data properly to do, I was able to achieve something similar using python notebook.
Json Format:
{
  "restaurant": [
    {
      "restaurant": "Bella Italia",
      "cuisine": "Italian",
      "rating": 5,
      "review": "Amazing pasta and great ambiance! Highly recommended."
    },
    {
      "restaurant": "Sushi Sakura",
      "cuisine": "Japanese",
      "rating": 4,
      "review": "Fresh sushi and friendly staff. A bit pricey but worth it."
    }
  ]
}

My app/api/add/route.js code is below:
import { Pinecone } from '@pinecone-database/pinecone';
import { OpenAI } from 'openai';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

// Initialize OpenAI and Pinecone clients with API keys
const openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY });
const pc = new Pinecone({ apiKey: process.env.PINECONE_API_KEY });
const index = pc.index('rag'); // Use the correct index name

// Function to handle user input
async function handleUserInput(userInput) {
    let records = [];

    // Check if input is an array or an object
    if (Array.isArray(userInput.restaurant)) {
        records = userInput.restaurant;
    } else {
        console.error('Invalid input format:', userInput);
        return [];
    }

    const processedData = [];

    for (const record of records) {
        console.log('Processing record:', record);

        // Ensure fields are properly mapped
        const mappedRecord = {
            restaurant: record.restaurant,
            review: record.review,
            cuisine: record.cuisine,
            rating: record.rating,
        };

        if (!mappedRecord.restaurant || !mappedRecord.review || !mappedRecord.cuisine || typeof mappedRecord.rating !== 'number') {
            console.error('Invalid record data:', mappedRecord);
            continue;
        }

        try {
            const response = await openai.embeddings.create({
                input: mappedRecord.review,
                model: 'text-embedding-3-small', // Ensure this model is available
            });

            const embedding = response.data?.[0]?.embedding;

            if (!Array.isArray(embedding)) {
                throw new Error('Embedding is not an array');
            }

            processedData.push({
                id: mappedRecord.restaurant, // Use 'restaurant' field for id
                values: embedding, // Embedding should be an array
                metadata: {
                    review: mappedRecord.review,
                    cuisine: mappedRecord.cuisine,
                    rating: mappedRecord.rating,
                },
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error creating embedding:', error.message);
        }
    }

    return processedData;
}

// Function to upsert data into Pinecone
async function upsertData(processedData) {
    try {
        // Ensure processedData is in the correct format
        const formattedData = processedData.map(record => ({
            id: record.id,
            values: record.values,
            metadata: record.metadata,
        }));

        // Perform upsert operation
        const upsertResponse = await index.upsert({
            vectors: formattedData,
            namespace: 'ns1', // Replace with your namespace if needed
        });

        console.log(`Upserted count: ${upsertResponse.upserted_count}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error upserting data into Pinecone:', error.message);
        throw new Error('Failed to upsert data');
    }
}

// Function to print index statistics
async function printIndexStats() {
    try {
        const stats = await index.describeIndexStats();
        console.log('Index statistics:', stats);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error describing index stats:', error.message);
    }
}

// POST request handler
export async function POST(req) {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Method not allowed' }), { status: 405 });
    }

    try {
        const body = await req.json();
        console.log('Received request body:', JSON.stringify(body, null, 2)); // Pretty print

        const processedData = await handleUserInput(body);

        if (processedData.length > 0) {
            await upsertData(processedData);
        } else {
            console.log('No valid data to upsert');
        }

        await printIndexStats();

        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Successfully added to lunch box' }), { status: 200 });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error adding restaurant:', error.message);
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: error.message || 'Internal Server Error' }), { status: 500 });
    }
}

Similar Implementation done here:
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
from pinecone import Pinecone, ServerlessSpec
from openai import OpenAI
import os
import json

# Initialize Pinecone
pinecone = Pinecone(api_key=os.getenv("PINECONE_API_KEY"))

# Create a Pinecone index
pinecone.create_index(
    name="rag",
    dimension=1536,
    metric="cosine",
    spec=ServerlessSpec(cloud="aws", region="us-east-1"),
)

# Load the review data
with open("reviews.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# Initialize OpenAI client
client = OpenAI()

processed_data = []

# Create embeddings for each review
for review in data["restaurant"]:
    response = client.embeddings.create(
        input=review['review'], model="text-embedding-3-small"
    )
    embedding = response.data[0].embedding
    processed_data.append(
        {
            "values": embedding,
            "id": review["restaurant"],
            "metadata": {
                "review": review["review"],
                "cuisine": review["cuisine"],
                "rating": review["rating"],
            }
        }
    )

# Insert the embeddings into the Pinecone index
index = pinecone.Index("rag")
upsert_response = index.upsert(
    vectors=processed_data,
    namespace="ns1"
)

print("Upsert response:", upsert_response)

# Print index statistics
index_stats = index.describe_index_stats()
print(index_stats)

Basically I am trying to achieve what I have done in python, through javascript.
My error are below:
○ Compiling /api/add ...
 ✓ Compiled /api/add in 1273ms (1168 modules)
Failed to find any user-provided fetch implementation. Using global fetch implementation.
Failed to find any user-provided fetch implementation. Using global fetch implementation.
Received request body: {
  "restaurant": {
    "name": "Popeyes Louisiana Kitchen",
    "rating": 4.6,
    "cuisine": "Fast-food",
    "review": "This is not the first time, last visit the food was clearly refried to be warmed up. This time, all the wraps are dripping with half a bottle of sause in each wrap. Inedible food. I would like my money back. My dog is served better food."
  }
}
Invalid input format: {
  restaurant: {
    name: 'Popeyes Louisiana Kitchen',
    rating: 4.6,
    cuisine: 'Fast-food',
    review: 'This is not the first time, last visit the food was clearly refried to be warmed up. This time, all the wraps are dripping with half a bottle of sause in each wrap. Inedible food. I would like my money back. My dog is served better food.'
  }
}
No valid data to upsert
Failed to find any user-provided fetch implementation. Using global fetch implementation.
Failed to find any user-provided fetch implementation. Using global fetch implementation.
Index statistics: {
  namespaces: { ns1: { recordCount: 20 } },
  dimension: 1536,
  indexFullness: 0,
  totalRecordCount: 20
}
 POST /api/add 200 in 2870ms

